# What is the function of this function here?

Tags: php

I'm studying some code and I found this:

```
$linkDirectToApp=preg_replace('/\s+/', '', 'https://example.com/'.$subdo);
```

What exactly is preg_replace doing to my url and how can I disable it?

Comment: *"What exactly is preg_replace doing to my url"* - it replaces spaces with nothing. *"and how can I disable it?"* - **huh, why?**

Comment: disable = delete? or just comment out

Comment: @Dagon *disabled* means "can't walk and/or talk". So, I'd throw it over the edge and let nature take its course.

Comment: `if(condition == x) { do something }` as in `if()` it contains a space....`{...}` - `else{...}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It removes spaces:
`\s` - Whitespace
`+` - 1 or more
`\s+` - means 1 or more whitespaces.

To disable it just change your line with:

```
$linkDirectToApp = 'https://example.com/'.$subdo;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "this is a url";
echo $url."<br/>";
preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $url);
echo $url;
**The Output will  be** 
this is a url
this is a url
```

The function **preg_replace** doesn't modify the string in-place. It returns a new string with the result of the space removed.

```
$url1 = "this is a url";
echo $url1."<br/>";
$url2 = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $url1);
echo $url2;
**The Output will  be** 
this is a url
thisisaurl
```

In this case it removes the **white space** in this string (https://example.com/'.$subdo) with **empty** and assigns it to $linkDirectToApp.

To disable the **preg_replace**, replace the variable with the below string.

```
$linkDirectToApp="https://example.com/$subdo";
```